# rxjava + retrofit streaming one by one a long list of data

Tags: android, rx-java, gson

I need to get list of users:

API Endpoint:

```
Observable<List<User>> getUsers();

onNext(List<User> usersList)
```

I do not want to wait for the download of entire list.

I want to get user one by one.
Like this:

```
onNext(TempData singleUser)
```

how can I do that?

Comment: I think Retrofit won't be able to do that. You'll need to download the data yourself. You can still wrap the result in an `Observable` using `Observable.create`. Just make sure to fulfill the Observable contract.

Comment: take a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330983/get-json-object-one-by-one-from-json-array-in-android-using-retrofit-and-rxjava/40187125#40187125

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert `Observable<List<User>>` to `Observable<User>`, you can use `getUsers().flatMapIterable(l -> l)`.

If you want to downloads and process the user list one by one, you need to change your API, since `Observable<List<User>> getUsers()` won't emit anything until the whole list is downloaded.