# Get JSON object one by one from JSON array in Android using Retrofit and RxJava

Tags: android, json, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am using retrofit to hit my network api which returns json array. I am doing so using following code-

```
Observable<MyJson[]> response = (Observable<MyJson[]>)mNetworkService.getReadyObserverable(mNetworkService.getNetworkServiceApi().getMyDataJsons(), MyJson.class, true, useCache);
        mAirlineSubscription = response.subscribe(new Observer<MyJson[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d(TAG, "getData completed..");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: "  + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(MyJson[] myJsonData) {
                //I want here json data one by one
            }
```

But my problem is json data array get downloaded completely and then only 
`onNext` gets called. Here I want `onNext` should get called when retrofit downloads first json object from `myData[]` json array and keep continue until my all json objects of `myData[]` get downloaded. This way my UI would look more responsive and better in terms of user interaction.

Can anyone help to fix this?

Comment: Retrofit does not support this out of the box - custom `CallAdapter` and `Converter` are needed. Both are required - in CallAdapter, `ResponseBody`'s stream must be processed (get individual array items) AND converted to java objects, and Converter should just pass those results as is (noop). First, this contradicts retrofit's design, where CallAdapter and Converter are independent entities.Second, implementation would be nontrivial and lengthy - json streaming parsing, rxjava backpressure etc - i suggest you to find another solution to problem - data paging, smaller response etc

Answer (score 3):

**Receiving elements One by One, as fast as possible?
Don't want to wait when everything will be downloaded?**

The solution is: Declare the method of retrofit's interface with annotation `@Streaming` and use `Observable<ResponseBody>` as return value. And then, by using `flatMap()`, convert `ResponseBody` to series of POJO (`Observable<TYPE>`).

**Example:**

1. Declare retrofit interface:

   ```js
   public interface HugeJsonApi {

   String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com";

   @Streaming
   @GET("/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json/master/citylots.json")
   Observable<ResponseBody> get();
   }
   ```
2. Use it like that:

   ```js
   public void playHugeJsonSample() {

       HugeJsonApi hugeJsonApi = RestUtils.createService(HugeJsonApi.class, HugeJsonApi.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);

       Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       hugeJsonApi.get()
               .flatMap(responseBody -> convertObjectsStream(responseBody, gson, Feature.class))
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribe(new Subscriber<Feature>() {

                   @Override
                   public void onStart() {
                       super.onStart();
                       request(1);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onNext(Feature feature) {
                       Log.i(TAG, gson.toJson(feature));
                       counter[0]++;
                       request(1);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted() {
                       Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted() called. Fetched elements:" + counter[0]);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) {
                       Log.e(TAG, "something went wrong", e);
                   }
               });
   }

   @NonNull
   private static <TYPE> Observable<TYPE> convertObjectsStream(ResponseBody responseBody, Gson gson, Class<TYPE> clazz) {
       Type type = TypeToken.get(clazz).getType();
       return Observable.create(SyncOnSubscribe.<JsonReader, TYPE>createStateful(
               // initialize the reader
               () -> {
                   try {
                       JsonReader reader = gson.newJsonReader(responseBody.charStream());
                       reader.beginObject();
                       return reader;
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       RxJavaHooks.onError(e);
                   }
                   return null;
               },
               // read elements one by one
               (reader, observer) -> {

                   if (reader == null) {
                       observer.onCompleted();
                       return null;
                   }

                   try {
                       if (reader.hasNext()) {
                           TYPE t = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
                           observer.onNext(t);
                       }
                       else {
                           observer.onCompleted();
                       }

                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       observer.onError(e);
                   }

                   return reader;
               },
               // close the reader
               reader -> {
                   if (reader != null) {
                       try {
                           reader.close();
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                           RxJavaHooks.onError(e);
                       }
                   }
               }

       ));
   }
   ```

**Here is workable example:**

https://github.com/allco/RetrofitAndRxJava

It takes 180+Mb Json and parses it as a real stream.

Comment: @AndroDev, do you have any feedback?

Comment: not yet tried. was on vacation. will surely update you once I check.

Comment: Changed a bit the implementation according http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rx-java/2341/backpressure/10629/creating-backpressured-data-sources#t=201607290718331225652

Comment: What if i have another json array in same response like "features"
exp: {"features":[], "images":[]}
How do i parse this as a stream?

Comment: Well, all the magic happens at `convertObjectsStream`. Take a look at the middle lambda `(reader, observer) -> {...}`, open there an array with `JsonReader.beginArray()` and open then another one when the first will be exhausted. But then "features" and "imges" should be represented by the same Java interface/class (in this example by Feature.class) in order to be able to pass data further with `observer.onNext(t)`. Probably GsonDecoder could help here as well - the one which knows how to translate "features" and "images" to `Feature.class`

Comment: Yes i am having the problem in handling same interface for features and images. Can you provide a code sample for this? Or any link for help

Answer (score 1):

your service should look like this:

```
@GET("users/{username}/repos")
Observable<List<Repository>> publicRepositories(@Path("username") String username);
```

I mean, return a `Observable<List<Something>>`

Comment: OP wants list items as soon as they available - `Observable<Repository>` ,this approach still downloads all response and then issues single notification - `Observable<List<Repository>>`

Answer (score 1):

i have same question i explain it base of own project, you should use 
my retrofit request is

```
@GET("StudentApi/getAll")
    Observable<List<Person>> getPersons();
```

and i have an interface to run server request and it has this method for run getPersons() and return list of json array of persons info

```
Observable<Person> getAllPersons();
```

**and the important part is body of up method and should like bellow**

```
@Override
    public Observable<Person> getAllPersons() {
        Observable<List<Person>> observable =
                serviceGenerator.getService().getPersons();
        return observable
                .flatMap(new Function<List<Person>, Observable<Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Person> apply(List<Person> persons) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.fromIterable(persons);
                    }
                });
}
```

i found that fromIterable method return objects of json array one by one
and finally in an activity i get json objects from up methods like bellow

```
public void getPersons(){
      personsRepository.getAllPersons()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Person>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Person value) {
                        Log.e("person info  is",value.getpName() + value.getpFamily());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("onError",throwable.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.e("onComplete","onComplete");
                    }
                });
    }
```

i hope is useful :)